# Why ++var++ is not a legal Javascript expression?

Tags: javascript, expression

I was reading about Javascript operators precedence [over here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and got curious why I can't write something like this:

```
let num = 1;
++num++;
```

Which gets `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation` error. But why is that? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It evaluates as

```
++(num++)
```

so, the expression

```
num++
```

returns a number, not the variable, because it is a primitive value. The added plusses, throws an exception, because a primitive value is not a variable and an assigment is not possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Just `num++` is evaluated first, but the essence remains the same. Thanks, my curiosity needs satisfied! :)